# jlist get and set selection broken?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist

What the program should do:

After the user clicks the "delete" button with a word selected from the list on the word manager gui window, another item (any item) from the word list should be selected (highlighted on the gui) so that the user doesn't have to click back and forth to delete a series of words from the list.

I refer you to the following code snippet to illustrate the problem further:

```
logic.words.remove(w);
logic.save_words_to_disk();
populate_list();
word_list.setSelectedIndex(0); //doesn't make the selection in the list
```

The above code snippet can be used to run a "find" search in the browser to locate the section of code I am referring too. Also, to illustrate what I mean, the list should be populated with a few items beforehand (an empty list obviously won't do when testing this).

What happens:

The selected word is deleted, but, apparently, the method call word_list.setSelectedIndex(...) has no effect, as nothing is selected after it is called. The method getSelectedIndex() also doesn't work, but I've used a work around (list selection listener) to get the currently selected index in the list, but its ugly (not elegant).

My question:

What am I doing wrong? I've tried the set list selection method in a simple program and it works fine, but for some reason, it doesn't work in my main project. I've posted the full source code for both my main project and the simple test project below.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---MAIN PROJECT---

```
package spellingbee;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class SpellingBee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create objects
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        Logic logic = new Logic();

        //link objects
        gui.logic = logic;
        logic.gui = gui;
        AudioRecorder.logic = logic;


        //start program
        AudioRecorder.init();
        gui.initialize();

        logic.load_words_from_disk();
        logic.choose_word();
        logic.prompt_word();
    }
}

class GUI {

    //this link is set externally
    public Logic logic = null;
    public WordManager word_manager = null;
    public MainGUI main_gui = null;

    public void initialize() {



        main_gui = new MainGUI();
        word_manager = new WordManager();

    }

    public void show_word_manager() {
        word_manager.populate_list();
        word_manager.window.setLocationRelativeTo(main_gui.window);
        word_manager.window.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MainGUI {

        public JLabel input_label = null;
        public JLabel last_word_label = null;
        JFrame window = null;

        public MainGUI() {
            window = new JFrame("Spelling Bee");
            window.addKeyListener(new Keyboard());
            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            input_label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
            input_label.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 32));
            input_label.setFocusable(false);
            input_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));

            last_word_label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
            last_word_label.setFont(new Font("", Font.ITALIC, 16));
            last_word_label.setFocusable(false);
            last_word_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 30));

            JLabel help_label_1 = new JLabel("Press '0' to hear the current word.", JLabel.CENTER);
            JLabel help_label_2 = new JLabel("Press '1' to manage word list.", JLabel.CENTER);

            JPanel help_panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            help_panel.add(help_label_1);
            help_panel.add(help_label_2);

            window.getContentPane().add(input_label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            window.getContentPane().add(last_word_label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            window.getContentPane().add(help_panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    class WordManager {

        public JDialog window = null;
        public JList word_list = null;
        public DefaultListModel list_model = null;
        public JButton delete_button = null;
        public JButton record_button = null;
        public int list_selection;
        public JTextField input_field = null;

        public WordManager() {

            window = new JDialog(main_gui.window, "Word Viewer", true);
            //window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

            list_model = new DefaultListModel();
            DefaultListSelectionModel dlsm = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
            dlsm.clearSelection();
            word_list = new JList(list_model);
            word_list.setSelectionModel(dlsm);
            word_list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            word_list.addListSelectionListener(new SelectionManager());

            JScrollPane word_list_scroll_pane = new JScrollPane(word_list);
            word_list_scroll_pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 300));

            ButtonManager button_manager = new ButtonManager();

            delete_button = new JButton("Delete");
            delete_button.setActionCommand("delete_button");
            delete_button.addActionListener(button_manager);
            //delete_button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

            record_button = new JButton("Record");
            record_button.setActionCommand("start_record");
            record_button.addActionListener(button_manager);

            input_field = new JTextField(15);

            JPanel record_panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            record_panel.add(input_field);
            record_panel.add(record_button);

            JPanel east_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            east_panel.add(delete_button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            east_panel.add(record_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            window.add(word_list_scroll_pane, BorderLayout.WEST);
            window.add(east_panel, BorderLayout.EAST);

            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(main_gui.window);


        }

        public void populate_list() {

            //this code creates a thread on the event dispatch thread
            //which is needed for gui actions. not doing this for gui
            //operations can cause unpredictable errors that are
            //difficult to reproduce
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    populate_list_helper();
                }
            });
        }

        private void populate_list_helper() {
            //this line will determine whether or not a block of code is running
            //on the event dispatching thread
            //System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

            list_model.clear();

            for (Word w : logic.words) {
                list_model.addElement(w.spelling);
            }
        }

        class SelectionManager implements ListSelectionListener {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                list_selection = e.getFirstIndex();
            }
        }

        class ButtonManager implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String action_command = e.getActionCommand();
                if (action_command.equals("delete_button")) {
                    int selection = list_selection;
                    if (selection != -1) {
                        String selected_string = word_list.getModel().getElementAt(selection).toString();

                        for (Word w : logic.words) {
                            if (w.spelling.equals(selected_string)) {
                                logic.words.remove(w);
                                logic.save_words_to_disk();
                                populate_list();
                                word_list.setSelectedIndex(0);

                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (action_command.equals("start_record")) {
                    if (!input_field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        record_button.setActionCommand("stop_record");
                        record_button.setText("Stop Recording");
                        logic.start_recording();
                    } else {
                        SoundPlayer.play("wrong.wav");
                    }
                } else if (action_command.equals("stop_record")) {
                    record_button.setActionCommand("start_record");
                    logic.stop_recording();
                    record_button.setText("Record");
                    input_field.grabFocus();
                    input_field.selectAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            logic.process_keyboard_input(e);
        }
    }
}

class Logic {

    public GUI gui = null;
    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    Word current_word = null;
    //public byte[] sound_data = null;

    public void save_words_to_disk() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src\\spellingbee\\words.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(words);

            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("save_words_to_disk: " + e);
        }

    }

    public void load_words_from_disk() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src\\spellingbee\\words.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            words = (ArrayList<Word>) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("load_words_from_disk: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void start_recording() {
        AudioRecorder.captureAudio();
    }

    public void stop_recording() {
        AudioRecorder.stopCapture = true;
    }

    public void process_new_word(byte[] sound_data) {
        Word temp_word = new Word(gui.word_manager.input_field.getText(), sound_data);
        words.add(temp_word);
        temp_word.play();

        if (words.size() == 1) {
            choose_word();
        }

        gui.word_manager.populate_list();
        save_words_to_disk();
    }

    public void choose_word() {
        if (current_word != null) {
            String old_word = current_word.spelling;

            if (words.size() > 1) {
                while (old_word.equals(current_word.spelling)) {
                    current_word = words.get(new Random().nextInt(words.size()));
                }
            } else {
                current_word = words.get(0);
            }
        } else {
            if (words.size() > 0) {
                current_word = words.get(new Random().nextInt(words.size()));
            }

        }
    }

    public void prompt_word() {
        if (current_word != null) {
            current_word.play();
        }
    }

    public void process_keyboard_input(KeyEvent e) {
        char user_input = e.getKeyChar();

        //verify input
        if (!input_ok(user_input)) {
            return;
        }

        switch (user_input) {
            case '0':
                prompt_word();
                return;
            case '1':
                gui.show_word_manager();
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }

        String result_string = gui.main_gui.input_label.getText();

        gui.main_gui.input_label.setText(result_string + Character.toString(user_input));

        result_string = gui.main_gui.input_label.getText();

        String answer_string = current_word.spelling;

        if (result_string.equalsIgnoreCase(answer_string)) {
            SoundPlayer.play("ding.wav");
            gui.main_gui.last_word_label.setText(gui.main_gui.input_label.getText().toLowerCase());
            gui.main_gui.input_label.setText("");
            choose_word();
            prompt_word();
        }

        //check to see if input is correct so far
        int result_length = result_string.length();
        String partial_result = result_string.substring(0, result_length);
        String partial_answer = answer_string.substring(0, result_length);
        if (!partial_result.equalsIgnoreCase(partial_answer)) {
            SoundPlayer.play("wrong.wav");
            gui.main_gui.input_label.setText("");
        }


    }

    public boolean input_ok(char input_value) {
        boolean result = false;

        switch (new Character(input_value).toString().toLowerCase().charAt(0)) {
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case 'd':
            case 'e':
            case 'f':
            case 'g':
            case 'h':
            case 'i':
            case 'j':
            case 'k':
            case 'l':
            case 'm':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case 'p':
            case 'q':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'y':
            case 'z':
            case '0':
            case '1':
                result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Word implements Serializable {

    public String spelling = null;
    public byte[] audio_data = null;

    public Word(String spelling, byte[] audio_data) {
        this.spelling = spelling;
        this.audio_data = audio_data;
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void play() {
        SoundPlayer.play_data(audio_data);
    }
}

class SoundPlayer {

    static AudioFormat audio_format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);

    static public void play(String path) {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

            InputStream audio_src = SpellingBee.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            InputStream buffered_in = new BufferedInputStream(audio_src);
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(buffered_in);

            clip.open(audioStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static public void play_data(byte[] data) {
        Clip clip = null;
        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("1 " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {

            clip.open(audio_format, data, 0, data.length);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("2a " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("2b " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.err.println("2c " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.err.println("2d " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("3 " + e.getMessage());
        }



    }
}

class AudioRecorder {

    static boolean stopCapture = false;
    static ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    static AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);
    static TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    static private byte[] audioData = null;
    public static Logic logic = null;

    static public byte[] get_audio_data() {
        return audioData;
    }

    static public void init() {
        try {
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    static public void captureAudio() {
        try {
            targetDataLine.start();
            //Create a thread to capture the microphone data and start it
            //running. It will run until the Stop button is clicked.
            Thread captureThread = new Thread(new CaptureThread());
            captureThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("4 " + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }//end catch
    }//end captureAudio method

    static class CaptureThread extends Thread {
        //An arbitrary-size temporary holding buffer

        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            stopCapture = false;
            try {
                //stopCapture will be set by another thread
                while (!stopCapture) {
                    //Read data from the internal buffer of the data line.
                    int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
                    if (cnt > 0) {
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                    }
                }

                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                audioData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                logic.process_new_word(audioData);
                System.out.println();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("capture thread " + e);
                System.exit(0);
            }//end catch
        }//end run
    }//end inner class CaptureThread
}//end outer class AudioCapture01.java
```

---TEST PROJECT---

```
package testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String[] items = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"};
        final JList list = new JList(items);
        list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("select random item");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                list.setSelectedIndex(new Random().nextInt(11));
            }
        }
        );

        frame.getContentPane().add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple why your code does not work:

1. The user presses delete
2. You remove the selected word from your "Model"
3. You call `populate_list()` where you call `invokeLater` which will invoke later `populate_list_helper()`
4. You select the index 0
5. `populate_list_helper()` gets called
6. You clear the list, which also resets the selection
7. You rebuild the list but you don't set back the selection

Question:

Why do you use invokeLater while you are already on the EDT (`ActionEvent` only occurs on the EDT, that's the whole point of EDT)? (Remember that EDT stands for Event Dispatching Thread)

You have several options here:

1. Call directly `populate_list_helper()` instead of calling it in `invokeLater`
2. In `populate_list_helper()` restore the previous selection after repopulating your list.

NB: Any reason for preventing multiple selection? This would be a lot friendlier to the end-user. He could delete several words in a single action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Guillaume. I was going to post answers to your questions here (the comment box) but I am limited in the number of characters that can appear here. And I can't seem to undo the post, so see below for my answers.

Comment: Guillaume, you are awesome. After calling populate_list_helper() directly (instead of calling it with invokeLater), setting the selection on the list worked perfectly. I see now that it was because of the new thread that populate_list_helper was being run on which caused the selected index on the list to be reset. Question: if I called populate_list_helper with invokeAndWait (which causes the thread to block until it has finished executing) instead of invokeLater, the selection shouldn't be reset either, correct?

Answer (score 0):

And here is the updated code that implements the solution to my problem.

```
package spellingbee;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class SpellingBee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create objects
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        Logic logic = new Logic();

        //link objects
        gui.logic = logic;
        logic.gui = gui;
        AudioRecorder.logic = logic;


        //start program
        AudioRecorder.init();
        gui.initialize();

        logic.load_words_from_disk();
        logic.choose_word();
        logic.prompt_word();
    }
}

class GUI {

    //this link is set externally
    public Logic logic = null;
    public WordManager word_manager = null;
    public MainGUI main_gui = null;

    public void initialize() {



        main_gui = new MainGUI();
        word_manager = new WordManager();

    }

    public void show_word_manager() {
        word_manager.populate_list_on_new_thread();
        word_manager.window.setLocationRelativeTo(main_gui.window);
        word_manager.window.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MainGUI {

        public JLabel input_label = null;
        public JLabel last_word_label = null;
        JFrame window = null;

        public MainGUI() {
            window = new JFrame("Spelling Bee");
            window.addKeyListener(new Keyboard());
            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            input_label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
            input_label.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 32));
            input_label.setFocusable(false);
            input_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));

            last_word_label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
            last_word_label.setFont(new Font("", Font.ITALIC, 16));
            last_word_label.setFocusable(false);
            last_word_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 30));

            JLabel help_label_1 = new JLabel("Press '0' to hear the current word.", JLabel.CENTER);
            JLabel help_label_2 = new JLabel("Press '1' to manage word list.", JLabel.CENTER);

            JPanel help_panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            help_panel.add(help_label_1);
            help_panel.add(help_label_2);

            window.getContentPane().add(input_label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            window.getContentPane().add(last_word_label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            window.getContentPane().add(help_panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    class WordManager {

        public JDialog window = null;
        public JList word_list = null;
        public DefaultListModel list_model = null;
        public JButton delete_button = null;
        public JButton record_button = null;
        public int list_selection;
        public JTextField input_field = null;

        public WordManager() {

            window = new JDialog(main_gui.window, "Word Viewer", true);
            //window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

            list_model = new DefaultListModel();
            DefaultListSelectionModel dlsm = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
            dlsm.clearSelection();
            word_list = new JList(list_model);
            word_list.setSelectionModel(dlsm);
            word_list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            word_list.addListSelectionListener(new SelectionManager());

            JScrollPane word_list_scroll_pane = new JScrollPane(word_list);
            word_list_scroll_pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 300));

            ButtonManager button_manager = new ButtonManager();

            delete_button = new JButton("Delete");
            delete_button.setActionCommand("delete_button");
            delete_button.addActionListener(button_manager);
            //delete_button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));

            record_button = new JButton("Record");
            record_button.setActionCommand("start_record");
            record_button.addActionListener(button_manager);

            input_field = new JTextField(15);

            JPanel record_panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            record_panel.add(input_field);
            record_panel.add(record_button);

            JPanel east_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            east_panel.add(delete_button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            east_panel.add(record_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            window.add(word_list_scroll_pane, BorderLayout.WEST);
            window.add(east_panel, BorderLayout.EAST);

            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(main_gui.window);


        }





        //CODE REVISIONS START HERE*********************************
        //(see code within ButtonManager below for additional changes)

        public void populate_list_on_new_thread() {

            //this code creates a thread on the event dispatch thread
            //which is needed for gui actions. not doing this for gui
            //operations can cause unpredictable errors that are
            //difficult to reproduce
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    populate_list();
                }
            });
        }


        //this method populates the list without creating a new thread
        public void populate_list() {
            //this line will determine whether or not a block of code is running
            //on the event dispatching thread
            //System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

            list_model.clear();

            for (Word w : logic.words) {
                list_model.addElement(w.spelling);
            }
        }

        //CODE REVISIONS END HERE*********************************





        class SelectionManager implements ListSelectionListener {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                list_selection = e.getFirstIndex();
            }
        }

        class ButtonManager implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String action_command = e.getActionCommand();
                if (action_command.equals("delete_button")) {
                    int selection = list_selection;
                    if (selection != -1) {
                        String selected_string = word_list.getModel().getElementAt(selection).toString();

                        for (Word w : logic.words) {
                            if (w.spelling.equals(selected_string)) {
                                logic.words.remove(w);
                                logic.save_words_to_disk();


                                //CODE REVISIONS START HERE*********************************
                                //(see populate_list() and populate_list_on_new_thread() definitions above for additional changes

                                populate_list(); //doesn't invoke a new thread; should finish before selection is made, so as not to clear the selection once the list is repopulated

                                //this makes sure something is selected
                                if(selection >= word_list.getModel().getSize()) {
                                    selection = word_list.getModel().getSize() - 1;
                                }

                                word_list.setSelectedIndex(selection);

                                //CODE REVISIONS END HERE*********************************


                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (action_command.equals("start_record")) {
                    if (!input_field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        record_button.setActionCommand("stop_record");
                        record_button.setText("Stop Recording");
                        logic.start_recording();
                    } else {
                        SoundPlayer.play("wrong.wav");
                    }
                } else if (action_command.equals("stop_record")) {
                    record_button.setActionCommand("start_record");
                    logic.stop_recording();
                    record_button.setText("Record");
                    input_field.grabFocus();
                    input_field.selectAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            logic.process_keyboard_input(e);
        }
    }
}

class Logic {

    public GUI gui = null;
    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    Word current_word = null;
    //public byte[] sound_data = null;

    public void save_words_to_disk() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src\\spellingbee\\words.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(words);

            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("save_words_to_disk: " + e);
        }

    }

    public void load_words_from_disk() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src\\spellingbee\\words.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            words = (ArrayList<Word>) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("load_words_from_disk: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void start_recording() {
        AudioRecorder.captureAudio();
    }

    public void stop_recording() {
        AudioRecorder.stopCapture = true;
    }

    public void process_new_word(byte[] sound_data) {
        Word temp_word = new Word(gui.word_manager.input_field.getText(), sound_data);
        words.add(temp_word);
        temp_word.play();

        if (words.size() == 1) {
            choose_word();
        }

        gui.word_manager.populate_list_on_new_thread();
        save_words_to_disk();
    }

    public void choose_word() {
        if (current_word != null) {
            String old_word = current_word.spelling;

            if (words.size() > 1) {
                while (old_word.equals(current_word.spelling)) {
                    current_word = words.get(new Random().nextInt(words.size()));
                }
            } else {
                current_word = words.get(0);
            }
        } else {
            if (words.size() > 0) {
                current_word = words.get(new Random().nextInt(words.size()));
            }

        }
    }

    public void prompt_word() {
        if (current_word != null) {
            current_word.play();
        }
    }

    public void process_keyboard_input(KeyEvent e) {
        char user_input = e.getKeyChar();

        //verify input
        if (!input_ok(user_input)) {
            return;
        }

        switch (user_input) {
            case '0':
                prompt_word();
                return;
            case '1':
                gui.show_word_manager();
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }

        String result_string = gui.main_gui.input_label.getText();

        gui.main_gui.input_label.setText(result_string + Character.toString(user_input));

        result_string = gui.main_gui.input_label.getText();

        String answer_string = current_word.spelling;

        if (result_string.equalsIgnoreCase(answer_string)) {
            SoundPlayer.play("ding.wav");
            gui.main_gui.last_word_label.setText(gui.main_gui.input_label.getText().toLowerCase());
            gui.main_gui.input_label.setText("");
            choose_word();
            prompt_word();
        }

        //check to see if input is correct so far
        int result_length = result_string.length();
        String partial_result = result_string.substring(0, result_length);
        String partial_answer = answer_string.substring(0, result_length);
        if (!partial_result.equalsIgnoreCase(partial_answer)) {
            SoundPlayer.play("wrong.wav");
            gui.main_gui.input_label.setText("");
        }


    }

    public boolean input_ok(char input_value) {
        boolean result = false;

        switch (new Character(input_value).toString().toLowerCase().charAt(0)) {
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case 'd':
            case 'e':
            case 'f':
            case 'g':
            case 'h':
            case 'i':
            case 'j':
            case 'k':
            case 'l':
            case 'm':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case 'p':
            case 'q':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'y':
            case 'z':
            case '0':
            case '1':
                result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Word implements Serializable {

    public String spelling = null;
    public byte[] audio_data = null;

    public Word(String spelling, byte[] audio_data) {
        this.spelling = spelling;
        this.audio_data = audio_data;
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void play() {
        SoundPlayer.play_data(audio_data);
    }
}

class SoundPlayer {

    static AudioFormat audio_format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);

    static public void play(String path) {
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

            InputStream audio_src = SpellingBee.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            InputStream buffered_in = new BufferedInputStream(audio_src);
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(buffered_in);

            clip.open(audioStream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static public void play_data(byte[] data) {
        Clip clip = null;
        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("1 " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {

            clip.open(audio_format, data, 0, data.length);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("2a " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("2b " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.err.println("2c " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.err.println("2d " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("3 " + e.getMessage());
        }



    }
}

class AudioRecorder {

    static boolean stopCapture = false;
    static ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    static AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);
    static TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    static private byte[] audioData = null;
    public static Logic logic = null;

    static public byte[] get_audio_data() {
        return audioData;
    }

    static public void init() {
        try {
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    static public void captureAudio() {
        try {
            targetDataLine.start();
            //Create a thread to capture the microphone data and start it
            //running. It will run until the Stop button is clicked.
            Thread captureThread = new Thread(new CaptureThread());
            captureThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("4 " + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }//end catch
    }//end captureAudio method

    static class CaptureThread extends Thread {
        //An arbitrary-size temporary holding buffer

        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            stopCapture = false;
            try {
                //stopCapture will be set by another thread
                while (!stopCapture) {
                    //Read data from the internal buffer of the data line.
                    int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
                    if (cnt > 0) {
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                    }
                }

                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                audioData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                logic.process_new_word(audioData);
                System.out.println();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("capture thread " + e);
                System.exit(0);
            }//end catch
        }//end run
    }//end inner class CaptureThread
}//end outer class AudioCapture01.java
```

Comment: Rather than just posting a gigantic block of code, you should also highlight the changes that you made. It would also be a good idea to include little comments that explain how each change helped solve your problem.

Comment: The gigantic block of code you refer to was posted as a convenient way for anyone to copy and paste the code in order to quickly compile and run the program. However, you are correct in that changes should be highlighted and comments provided to explain the changes. I'll see if I can edit the source code that contains the changes to reflect these excellent ideas.

Comment: I didn't mean that the code wasn't useful, or that you should remove it. It's just very dense for people searching for the resolution to this problem.

Comment: Understood. You've been very helpful! I originally intended to include all the code so that anyone trying to help me had all the information they needed. I wasn't sure what could be causing my problem so I didn't want to leave anything out.

Comment: Oh, one last thing: if this is the resolution to your problem, you should mark this as the accepted answer (click the check mark under the vote count).